# How do you merge a feature branch in a Codeplex project?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, merge, codeplex

I have a project on [Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/) and I use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) to access the source code. I've created a feature branch and now I need to merge changes from the trunk into the feature branch. I'll need to eventually merge the feature branch back into the trunk as well. But it seems that [SvnBridge doesn't support merging](http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Current%20Feature%20Status)!

**Does anyone have suggestions on how to accomplish a merge on Codeplex?** Use Team Explorer for the merge? Or TF.exe or the Codeplex client?

Comment: I know a lot of projects only check-in version commits to Codeplex and keep the rest in a private version control setup. I never was a fan of Codeplex for being based on a proprietary version control system. The attempt to add an SVN interface is little more than an ugly band-aid.

Comment: I've noticed some projects also use Codeplex for a landing page and then point you to Google Code for the source code and issue tracker. I'd like to avoid that if possible. I was hoping that I could use a different VCS client to perform the merge and then go back to TortoiseSVN.

Comment: Perhaps I could create the main development tree somewhere else and then use svnsync to keep the Codeplex repository up to date? That way all of the heavy lifting is done elsewhere, but the source is still available at Codeplex.

Comment: It looks like Codeplex doesn't support svnsync either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [Codeplex now supports native mercurial](http://blogs.msdn.com/codeplex/archive/2010/01/22/codeplex-now-supporting-native-mercurial.aspx), I think I'm going to try that. I've been wanting try out a [DVCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control) anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

As you already have TortoiseSVN, you could simply use it alone to perform the merge. Unless you end up with a lot of conflicts, a merge can easily be performed outside of any IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TortoiseSVN to simply merge you trunk to your branch and then back to the trunk. It can be done easily.

Check out a working copy of your branch, then right-click on the folder and then choose TortoiseSVN -> Merge...

Choose the first option and then choose the trunk. follow the directions on screen and test your merge before to see the results.

Same for the second merge back to the trunk.

Comment: Yes, that's how it should work. But codeplex does not support merging with a Subversion client.